# exception file not found - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

I write code for generate report using jasper report in java, I write following code to generate report from the mysql database using resultset.

```
JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);
System.out.println("Filling report...");
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("reports/DbReportDS.jasper", null, resultSetDataSource);
System.out.println("Done!");
```

when I execute this code it generates the following error

```
Filling report...
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: reports\DbReportDS.jasper
```

Comment: make sure you have included required jasper report jar files in your project.

Comment: yah, i have include all the jar files into project, even i also successfully execute code for generate pdf file using jrxml file but i want to generate report using resultres object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load jrxml located in jar file via JRXmlLoader: getting java.io.FileNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626140/cant-load-jrxml-located-in-jar-file-via-jrxmlloader-getting-java-io-filenotfou)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
URL in = this.getClass().getResource("/wifi/tickets/tickets.jasper");
report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(in);
```

Comment: prefer to write some explaination