# Accessing report inside a .jar file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, embedded-resource

So guys, as what the title implies. I cant access my report when i clean and build my program to a jar file to be deployed. I tried surfing the internet for possible solutions but none of them has gone right. So below is what i did to try to access the report inside the jar file:

```
URL reportURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("assessmentrecordsystem\\reports\\report1.jrxml");//returns nothing

reportInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("\\reports\\report1.jrxml");//all so returns nothing
```

What did i miss??

This is what my jar file contains:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read jrxml file inside the jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425079/how-to-read-jrxml-file-inside-the-jar-file) & [Why My Java Application can't see the *.jrxml?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20626140/876298) & [How to embed JasperReport sub-report into a jar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13322899/876298) & [Can't load jrxml located in jar file via JRXmlLoader: getting java.io.FileNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20626140/876298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a structure like this:

```
myjar.jar
  |__ assessmentrecordsystem
        |__ MyClass.class
        |__ reports
              |__ report1.jrxml
```

You can load the resource with a relative path from your MyClass with [getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("reports/report1.jrxml");
```

Otherwise, you need to add the following entry to the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside your jar:

```
Class-Path: .
```

Then you can load your file with an absolute path from the jar root with [getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        "/assessmentrecordsystem/reports/report1.jrxml");
```

Comment: my classes are not contained in the same directory.. take a look at the image i uploaded above.

Comment: keep getting **java.net.MalformedURLException** , what's is the cause and i moved the report so that it will be on the same directory as the class.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion but that doesn't solve the problem but i removed the **.getClassLoader()** part and it worked right. thanks.